# How to wire one/two or more microservice in the TwirpQL Server?

Tags: go, graphql, microservices, twirp

I'm using the `GraphQL server` which is most-often a gateway that bundles all my different `microservices` created using [`gqlgen`](https://gqlgen.com/).

I want to make a switch to the `TwirpQL server` as I was following the official documentation of [TwirpQL](https://twirpql.dev/docs/multiple-services). I believe it wants me to wrap every microservice inside it so there will be multiple GraphQL layers one for every microservice.

I don't want to expose the other microservices as `Graphql`, but rather "just" create one entry point for all the requests and later send them to the respected microservice accordingly.

Can anyone please enlighten me on the correct usage?

Thanks.